# Weblogic JDBC Exception : XAER_RMERR

Tags: weblogic9.x

any one have ever found this kind of exception in weblogic ?

[JDBCExceptionReporter] : Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: XA error: XAResource.XAER_RMERR start() failed on resource 'datasource/tx/olddata': XAER_RMERR : A resource manager error has occured in the transaction branch

we have application using Weblogic transaction manager to manage the transaction, the error happened when the application server take the data from a middleware server, when the data is received, the application server will try to insert the data to the database server, but the when it about to be commited it failed with above error.

anyone got any idea what might trig this kind of error ??

Answer (score 1):

This happen when you fire query across DB Link using XA Driver datasource. you can try separate Non Xa driver datasource for across DB Link queries.